# how can I repeat same cell value million time?

Tags: excel

my excel file, cell A2 have value "D"...I want to repeat this value 1,00,000 times in same column A. so A3 = "D", A4 = "D" , A5="D" and so on...

```
A   B
C   3
D   2
D   4
D   1
```

column B will have different values...I am using excel 2015. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub ButIRepeatMyself()
    Range("A3:A1000000").Value = Range("A2").Value
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: thanks but where to write this sub. I am new to Excel.